# Trouble with custom validation of Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I'm making a web app where the point is to change a given word by one letter. For example, if I make a post by selecting the word: "best," then the first reply could be "rest," while the one after that should be "rent," "sent", etc. So, the word a user enters must have changed by one letter from the last submitted word. It would be constantly evolving.

Right now you can make a game and respond just by typing a word. I coded up a custom validation using functionality from the Amatch gem:

http://flori.github.com/amatch/doc/index.html

Posts have many responses, and responses belong to a post.

here's the code:

```
   def must_have_changed_by_one_letter
        m = Amatch::Sellers.new(title.strip)
        errors.add_to_base("Sorry, you must change the last submitted word by one letter")   
        if m.match(post.responses.last.to_s.strip) != 1.0
   end
```

When I try entering a new response for a test post I made (original word "best", first response is "rest") I get this:

ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid in ResponsesController#create
Validation failed: Sorry, you must change the last submitted word by one letter

Any thoughts on what might be wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: Got unit-tests for that method?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there are a couple of potential issues here.

For one, is your `if` statement actually on a separate line than your `errors.add_to_base...` statement? If so, your syntax is wrong; the `if` statement needs to be in the same line as the statement it's modifying. Even if it is actually on the correct line, I would recommend against using a trailing `if` statement on such a long line; it will make it hard to find the conditional.

```
if m.match(post.responses.last.to_s.strip) != 1.0
    errors.add_to_base("Sorry, you must change the last submitted word by one letter")
end
```

Second, doing exact equality comparison on floating point numbers is almost never a good idea. Because floating point numbers involve approximations, you will sometimes get results that are very close, but not quite exactly equal, to a given number that you are comparing against. It looks like the Amatch library has several different classes for comparing strings; the Sellers class allows you to set different weights for different kinds of edits, but given your problem description, I don't think you need that. I would try using the [Levenshtein](http://flori.github.com/amatch/doc/Amatch/Levenshtein.html) or [Hamming](http://flori.github.com/amatch/doc/Amatch/Hamming.html) distance instead, depending on your exact needs.

Finally, if neither of those suggestions work, try writing out to a log or in the response the exact values of `title.strip` and `post.responses.last.to_s.strip`, to make sure you are actually comparing the values that you think you're comparing. I don't know the rest of your code, so I can't tell you whether those are correct or not, but if you print them out somewhere, you should be easily able to check them yourself.

Comment: Thanks Brian, that helped. I believe I put the if statement on the same line, but I suppose it got clobbered when I hit submit.

The Hamming distance does seem to be a better match. Thanks for those recommendations. 

In the console:

post = Post.find_by_id(1)
post.responses.last.to_s
=>"#<Response:0x103275db8>"

So that's where the problem lay. It wasn't comparing the actual last response text, but the object ID. So I removed the to_s and replaced it with the title attribute of Response:

post.responses.last.title

I think that did the trick. Thanks for leading me in the right direction!